# Microsoft Speech через некоторое время после запуска программы перестает работать C#

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-speech-sdk

этот кусок кода отлично работает в другой форме

```
public IchiBot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeSpeechGrammar();
        }

public void InitializeSpeechGrammar()
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru");
            SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

            Choices choices = new Choices();
            choices.Add(new string[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре ", "запусти апекс" });

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Culture = ci;
            gb.Append(choices);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.80)
            {
                label1.Text = e.Result.Text;
            }
        }
```

а в моей программе перестает работать после 30-40ка секунд
как это исправить??
моя программа это телеграмм бот и я хотел его скрестить с голосовым ассистентом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Кажется GC уничтожает SpeechRecognitionEngine, так как он нигде не используется. Вынесите его из переменной в поле формы. `private SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;` а в методе просто `sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);`

Comment: Странно выглядит синхронный вызов явно асинхронной функции `RecognizeAsync`